# Why won't my upload_limit_rate for NGINX work?

Tags: file-upload, nginx

I am doing some testing on my local machine using the nginx upload module with the upload progress module. Because I am local, uploads are almost instant and it's hard to test and debug the upload progress module because of this.

I have added the directive: upload_limit_rate 8k to my nginx upload block as per the documentation: http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

After all this, uploading a file that is many megabytes is still instant... it seems
the upload rate limit is not working..

Here is my config block:

**FULL CONFIG can be found here:** http://pastie.org/4681229

---

location /upload {

```
# Pass altered request body to this location
    upload_pass   @unicorn;


    # Store files to this directory
    # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
    upload_store /Users/kirkquesnelle/Sites/porelo/tmp/uploads 1;

    # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
    upload_store_access user:r;

    # Set specified fields in request body
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

    # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
    upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
    upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";

    upload_pass_form_field "^X-Progress-ID|^authenticity_token|^submit$|^description$";

    upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;

    # Specifies upload rate limit in bytes per second. Zero means rate is unlimited.
    upload_limit_rate 8k;

    track_uploads proxied 30s;
```

}

---

Is there anything wrong with my config? Why would this not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `upload_limit_rate` before your `upload_pass` directive. As the first line in your config block.

Comment: K, thanks for response.. i'll try in a little bit and get back.

Comment: It seems i'm getting a 405 Not Allowed Error from my ajax callback when I try and call the progress hmm.. any ideas?

Comment: I've seen your question about this error, paste the content of your php script and your new nginx config, both.

Comment: Well I'm using Rails. But that part of the upload is working fine, it's just the calling of the upload_progress_module with a Ajax GET request. It's not liking how I'm calling it. I will post my entire NGINX config here:  http://pastie.org/4681229

Comment: I think this has something todo with me not setting up the proxy_pass correctly..

Comment: Remove the proxy_pass and try. But why did you even set a proxy_pass for upload location?

Comment: Was following a tutorial. As it turns out I have figured it out. I was doing alot of things wrong that are now fixed. Thanks so much for your efforts